# How to Use ReCaptcha with PHP Comment Form Using Single Page Verification

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I have successfully used ReCaptcha in my email form, but my comments section keeps getting spammed so I wanted to use it there.

However, I'm not sure how to implement the validation code for reCaptcha.

My email form uses a second page to post the data, so it works out fine, but my comment form has all the php code for posting the form on the same page.

When I tried to put in reCaptcha's verification code the way I did it before, but with the posting code on the same page, it caused the whole page to go blank upon loading.

Error reporting says:

> **Notice: Undefined index: recaptcha_challenge_field in /_assets/commentBox/podcastHeader.php on line 36**
>
> **Notice: Undefined index: recaptcha_response_field in /_assets/commentBox/podcastHeader.php on line 37**
>
> **The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.(reCAPTCHA said: incorrect-captcha-sol)**

So I guess it's trying to find the reCaptcha form right away and fails because nothing is filled out yet.

This is the relevant code I use for my form:

```
<?php
require_once('../../_assets/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "xxxxxx ";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
// Your code here to handle a successful verification
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$required_fields = array("author", "body");
validate_presences($required_fields);

if (empty($errors)) {
    $author = mysql_prep($_POST['author']);
    $body = mysql_prep($_POST['body']); 
    $page_name = ($_POST['page_name']);
    $current_time = date("Y-m-d H-i-s");
    
    $query  = "INSERT INTO comments (";
    $query .= "  author, body, page_name, created";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .= "  '{$author}', '{$body}', '{$page_name}', '{$current_time}'";
    $query .= ")";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    
    if ($result) {
        redirect_to("{$url}{$anchor}");
    } else {
            // Failure
            $_SESSION["message"] = "There was an error that prevented the comment from being saved.";
    }
}
} else {
    $author = "";
    $body = "";
}
}
$display_comments = find_comments();
?>
```

This is the comment form:

```
<div id="newComment">
    <h3 id="leaveComment">Leave a Comment!</h3>
    <?php echo message();  ?>
    <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>#comments" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_name" value="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" />
    <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Nickname" value="<?php echo $author; ?>" /><br>
    <textarea name="body" style="margin-top:5px" cols="40" rows="8" placeholder="What's on your mind?"><?php echo $body; ?></textarea><br>
    
    <div style="margin-top: 6px">
        <?php
            require_once('../../_assets/recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "xxxxxx";
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" style="margin-top:10px" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        <span style="margin-left: 8px">
        <a href="#title">Return to top</a>
        </div>
</form>
 </div>
```

Comment: I just checked my reCAPTCHA code...seems to be the same as yours.

Comment: Wait..one difference. I have my php reCAPCTHA code including the die(), inside my isset...you have it before your isset. Try it inside your isset but before your conditionals....if the reCAPCTHA is not entered properly the page will still die()

Comment: I just tried the change you suggested, but got the same result as before unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
>                               $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
>                               $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
>                               $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

This line checks the result immediately and since there was no check for POST data before, the page will die before doing anything.

Put the check inside the conditional:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer(...);
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        // Wrong captcha
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I think this may be what The One and Only ChemistryBlob was suggesting in the comments, but I guess I moved it around wrong earlier because it works perfectly now with your solution